# Suppress comment (#) when eval=FALSE in RMarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I want to use a lengthy data frame, but only display part of it in my slides.

````
```{r}
df1 = data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
df1
```
````

As you might guess, this produces output that won't fit in a presentation slide.

````
```{r eval=-2, echo=-3}
df1 = data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
df1
head(df1)
```
````

This produces:

```
df1 = data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
## df1

x       y
1  0.7699 -0.1683
2 -0.4756  0.3885
3 -0.6744  1.2755
4 -0.8533 -2.1271
5 -1.9129 -1.2661
6 -0.4567  0.5607
```

But I don't want the second code line to be commented out. At the moment, the only way I can figure out to do this is in two separate code chunks, because `eval=FALSE` does not result in commented code when it applies to the whole chunk.

This produces what I want:

````
```{r eval=FALSE}
df1 = data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
df1
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
df1 = data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
head(df1)
```
````

But obviously, if I change the code, I have to change it in two places. This is a simple example, but for more complex code, there is a greater danger of my code and results becoming out of sync as I edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

````
```{r include = FALSE}
library(knitr)
op <- knit_hooks$get()$source
knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) op(if(is.numeric(options$eval)) x[options$eval] else x, options))
```

```{r eval=-2, echo=-3}
df1 = data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
df1
head(df1)
```
````

This works with simple cases, but you need to refine if you will combine `echo` and `eval`.

Comment: Don't understand knitr that well, so I'm having a hard time tracing the logic of the function you created. When I tested the chunk, `eval=-2` works as expected, but `echo=-3` behaves like `echo=-c(2, 3)`. If I flip it to list lines that *should* (instead of should not) evaluate/echo with `{r eval=c(1, 3), echo=c(1, 2)}`, line two displays as `NA` instead of either `df1` (the desired goal) or `## df1` (the old, undesired behavior.